# How to enumerate paragraphs of an article using AppleScript?

Tags: loops, applescript

I'm desperately looking for a solution since a month, please help me.

Here is an example of the article i'm trying to modify :

"This is introduction.

This is paragraph 1 of some text.

This is paragraph 2 of some text.

This is paragraph 3 of some text.

This is paragraph 4 of some text.

This is paragraph 5 of some text.

This is outro"

What i'm trying to do is to enumerate each paragraph of the article so the article will look like this :

"This is introduction.

1. This is paragraph 1 of some text.
2. This is paragraph 2 of some text.
3. This is paragraph 3 of some text.
4. This is paragraph 4 of some text.
5. This is paragraph 5 of some text.

This is outro" .

Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, it skips the first and last paragraph and adds the ordinal number to the other paragraphs which is the index number - 1.

The result is collected in a list and joined at the end with `text item delimiters`.

```
set theText to "This is introduction.

This is paragraph 1 of some text.

This is paragraph 2 of some text.

This is paragraph 3 of some text.

This is paragraph 4 of some text.

This is paragraph 5 of some text.

This is outro"

set paragraphsOfText to paragraphs of theText
set paragraphList to {first item of paragraphsOfText, ""}
set counter to 1

repeat with i from 2 to ((count paragraphsOfText) - 1)
    set currentItem to item i of paragraphsOfText
    if length of currentItem is not 0 then
        set end of paragraphList to (counter as text) & ". " & currentItem
        set counter to counter + 1
    end if
end repeat
set end of paragraphList to ""
set end of paragraphList to last item of paragraphsOfText

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
set theResult to paragraphList as text
set text item delimiters to TID

display dialog theResult
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm going to try it :)

Comment: This works. What if the paragraphs were spaced with returns ? This is actually my case...

Comment: I updated the answer 5 minutes ago and added the returns

Comment: Thank you :) but the paragraphs in the theText aren't spaced with returns so when i try this to put returns the output changes...

Comment: And my texts are in files... sorry I should have said this first

Comment: It's very relieving to finally see things working after all this time of mash up coding. Thank you vadian. I will try to put the text of my file in a varialble and pass it to your code.